# Prove operator norm cannot be longer than len(basis) times max(norm(basis))operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional normed linear space and let
$T \in \mathscr L (V)$. Define the operator norm of $T$ to be the smallest number $M$ such
that $||T v|| ≤ M||v||$ for any $v \in V$ . We will write $||T||$ to mean that smallest
number $M$, the operator norm.

Let $B = e_1, ..., e_n$ be an orthonormal basis for V, a normed linear
space of dimension $n$. Let $T \in \mathscr L (V )$. Let
$m = Max\{||T e_1||, ||T e_2||, ..., ||T e_n||\}$. That is, $m$ is the length of the longest
vector in the list $T e_1, ..., T e_n$. Prove that for any vector $v \in V , ||Tv|| ≤ mn$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: What is $A$?  Does $A = T$?

Comment: I was confused about that too, may be a typo from the professor, let's treat A=T

Comment: As far as my thoughts go, I'm confused as to how why it's not simply $||Tv||\leq m$. Shouldn't the longest ||Tv|| be m since m is the max norm of the images of the basis?

Comment: I think you might need $\Vert Tv \Vert \le mn \Vert v \Vert$. since $\Vert Tv \Vert$ must depend on $v$.

Comment: The statement, as written, does not quite make sense. Only Hilbert spaces have orthonormal bases, other finite-dimensional normed spaces do not.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you need. Write $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i $ where $v_i = \langle v,e_i\rangle$. Then we have
$$
||Tv||^2 = ||\sum_{i=1}^n v_i T(e_i)||^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2\sum_{i=1}^n ||T(e_i)||^2\leq ||v||^2nm^2,
$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence, it follows that
$$
||T||\leq m\sqrt{n}.
$$